# how to remove all characters after and including "?" in filename?

Tags: scripting, terminal, filenames, rename

I have a large amount of files that were downloaded and ended up having what looks like authentication parameters added to the filename which I would like to remove. Examples:

```
file1.doc?b1h2uj3b123uiyb12
file2.xls?oi12jo3ij123oij
file3.jpg?0990xcizx0cxzczixuchbiasdu
```

Is there an easy way for me to strip everything after the question mark on the entire folder of files?

Comment: Are those the only files in the folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can match all filenames with a question mark with `*\?*`, and remove the part after the `?` from a variable with `${var%%\?*}`. The question mark itself is wildcard character, so has to be escaped in both cases.

A simple loop over the files and running `mv` should do:

```
for f in ./*\?*; do
    echo mv -n "$f" "${f%%\?*}"
done
```

(The `echo` is there so you can see what would be done before any changes being made. Remove it if the output looks sensible.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the Perl `rename` utility:

```
$ rename -v -n 's/[?].*//' *[?]*
rename(file1.doc?b1h2uj3b123uiyb12, file1.doc)
rename(file2.xls?oi12jo3ij123oij, file2.xls)
rename(file3.jpg?0990xcizx0cxzczixuchbiasdu, file3.jpg)
```

This applies the Perl substitution `s/[?].*//` to each name.  This would truncate the name just before the first question mark.  The `*[?]*` filename globbing pattern would expand to any name in the current directory that contains a question mark.

Run the command without `-n` to actually rename files.